# How to pass a list to view/layouts pages in grails

Tags: grails

I know how to pass parameter from controller to view. But I have a common view template `common.gsp`. Which is in `views/layouts` folder. I want to pass a list to `common.gsp`.

How can I do that without passing parameter from all action.

Answer (score 0):

You can use.

```
def ListOfObject=[]
render template: '/layouts/common', model: [desiredList: ListOfObject]
```